# Angularjs+karma+Jasmine:how to write jasmine test for child to verify if parent methods are called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using karma with jasmine for unit testing in my angularjs app.Given the following code snippet, i am try to check from child if parent method is called and i am facing issues as shown below.

ChildClass.js File

```
 var ChildClass= function () {
     this.id=null;
     ParentClass.apply(this,arguments);
 }; 

 function createParentObject(){             
            return new ParentClass();
        };

 ChildClass.prototype = createParentObject();

 ChildClass.prototype.testCall= function(value) {
    var self = this;  
    ParentClass.prototype.testCall.apply(this, arguments);
    self.id=1;
 }
```

ParentClass.js file

```
    var ParentClass= function () {
       this.title=null;
    }; 

    ParentClass.prototype.testCall= function(value) {
       var self = this;  
       self.title='test';
    }
```

My unit Test for ChildClass

```
  describe("MyFunction", function () {
     var parentClassMock,childClass;

       beforeEach(function () {
           var _parentClassMock=function(){
             this.title=null;
           }

          _parentClassMock.prototype.testCall= function(value) {
             var self = this;  
             self.title='test';
           }

          angular.module('childClassMocks', [])                 
                  .value('ParentClass', _parentClassMock);

         });

        beforeEach(function () {
          module('childClassMocks');
        });

      beforeEach(inject(function (_ChildClassA_,_ParentClass_) {
            parentClassMock= new _ParentClass_();
            childClass=new _ChildClass_(); 
             childClass.prototype = jasmine.createSpy("createParentObject").and.returnValue(parentClassMock);
      });
    it("test method", function () {
     spyOn(parentClassMock, 'testCall').and.callThrough();
     childClass.testCall();
     expect(parentClassMock.testCall).toHaveBeenCalled();

   });

 });
```

I am getting error as

```
   Expected spy testCall to have been called.
    Error: Expected spy testCall to have been called.
```

can anyone help how to write a jasmine test case to check if child has called parent?? i am not sure what was the issue in above code snipplet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `_ChildClass_.prototype = parentClassMock;` http://plnkr.co/edit/W38DSO?p=preview

Comment: Thank you,but you are using the really ParentClass but not the mocked parent class,is it possible to use the mocked parent not real parent class???

Comment: What do you mean by Really parentclass, isn't `parentClassMock` as mock?

Comment: What you did was wrong, childClass is instance of ChildClass, if you want to set prototype then you would do it on the class not on its instance. Ex. You say `[].slice.call` or `Array.prototype.slice.call`

Comment: I saw that you have created instance of real ParentClass and used it to spy on for ex:variable parentClassMock is instance of real ParentClass not the mock parent class _parentClassMock which i have mocked for this test to refer.

Comment: You have commented out this bit in the plunker   angular.module('childClassMocks', [])
            .value('ParentClass', _parentClassMock);

Comment: which Parent Class is the variable parentClassMock is refering to is it real Parent Class or mocked one???